# How to use GTK from just the source code (without installing it)

Tags: c, matlab, gtk, gtk3, simulink

I would like to be able to include gtk/gtk.h without doing any installations or builds (only building stuff when compiling the code) etc. This is because I'm using MATLAB coder to use a mixture of Simulink blocks and my own C-written Simulink blocks to generate C code which can then be deployed to a Raspberry Pi.

The best I think I can do, therefore, is to download C source code for GTK and give -I flags and -L flags in the compilation to tell the compiler where different header files and source code can be found. Is this possible, and if so, how can I do it?

Comment: I believe this will not be possible, simply because most of the code of GTK is *not* in its header files.

Comment: @zwol Thanks for the response. I can use .c or .cpp files as well (I've just edited the question to add that in). I'm just wondering if there's a folder (or a couple of folders) I can download containing all the .c and .h files for GTK (or any other C GUI package actually) which can be compiled using simple compilation commands and -I flags when I'm compiling all my other code. That would be my ideal scenario. Or do you mean the code is not even C/C++ either.

Comment: You can find GTK source code at GNOME's gitlab, however you still need to compile them to use.

Comment: @Sam______ Got it. Thanks. So is there no way to compile it without Meson and Ninja?

Comment: Actually, I definitely think I'm pushing it. I'm just going to make a standalone GUI app instead then communicate between the two using TCP. Thanks all for the assistance.